# If body has class then do this this etc

Tags: php, magento, if-statement, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

New to Magento (wordpress developer) and I'm struggling with this concept in Magento and not sure how to accomplish this with their api and set a varialbe of if body class = x

In short if the body has a class that is "x" then this happens (I'm trying target specific class's, so if a sub-page had a class of "other" for example, then it would run an if or elseif for that page):

```
<?php if ($this->getLayout()->createBlock("page/html")->getBodyClass() == 'home'): ?>

//add this content

<?php elseif($this->getLayout()->createBlock("page/html")->getBodyClass() == 'options'):?>

//add different divs content etc

<?php else: ?>

//stuff

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: do you need condition on body class exactly ? or need to condition for home page ?

Comment: @Asifhhh need condition for body class has a class that matches that.  So I guess exactly might work so to speak.  Sorry I should have specified that.  I'll update it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento if body class is x do something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982329/magento-if-body-class-is-x-do-something)

Comment: @ravipatel I deleted that post, could still be cashed

Comment: Not Pass duplicate Question your issue is fixed by using this one code. please use this on valid place of your layout.

Answer (score 2):

you can get the css class through

```
$this->getBodyClass()
```

used to work with block type

```
  Mage_Page_Block_Html
```

otherwise

```
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock("page/html")->getBodyClass();
```

Comment: would you do it like:
`$class = $this->getBodyClass();`
then the example of my BODY CLASS would be` if($class='sub'): ?> content <?php elseif($class='other'): ?> more stuff` etc ??`

Comment: I'm trying to have this in a template, header.phtml for example

Comment: every template file has a scope to $this, so you need to mention it exactly which template file ?

Comment: My fault, header.phtml for example, it will have different content depending on the body class

Comment: OK - if $this does not work then replace $this with $this->getLayout()->createBlock("page/html") and it will work

Comment: I updated my example, is that what you meant?
if not can you please update yours?

Comment: YES it is correct. But the class name for home appears 'cms-home' not only 'home'

Comment: ahh I've added classes to each template I am using.  So home has multple classes `cms-home` and `home`.  I want to target **specific** classes

Comment: so means you got success ? accept the answer for convenient of other users

Comment: No the code I have above in my example did not work as I am trying to target a specific body class

Comment: The quest was "In short if the body has a class that is "x" then this happens:"

So it was that I need to see if the body has a class that I am looking for then do the following

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

        $body_classes = $this->getLayout()->createBlock("page/html")->getBodyClass();

        if($body_classes=='cms-index-index'):

            //your code
        elseif($body_classes=='cms-page-view'):
            //your code

        else:    
            //your code
        endif;
      ?>
```